# Apex Test Class Throwing Error

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

I have an apex test class that is not working due to not having an appointment tied to it. I'm not sure how I've messed up. I know this is a beyond easy fix but I've been looking at it for too long and I'd like an outside perspective.

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Cannot add a sale with a
>   missing appointment: [i360__Appointment__c]

Here is the apex test class.

```
@isTest
private class HomeDepotStoreTest {
    static testMethod void TestHomeDepotStores()
    {
       i360__Staff__c staff = new i360__Staff__c();
       staff.Name = '2036';
       insert staff;

       i360__Prospect__c Pros = new i360__Prospect__c();
       Pros.Name ='Bob Joe';
       Pros.Referral_Store__c = '2036';
       Pros.i360__Phone_1__c = '(123) 123-1234';
       Pros.i360__Primary_Last_Name__c = 'TESTMCTEST';
       insert Pros;

       i360__Appointment__c App = new i360__Appointment__c();
       App.Name = '2036';
       App.i360__Prospect__c = Pros.Id;   

       i360__Sale__c a = new i360__Sale__c();
       a.Name ='2036';
       a.i360__Appointment__c = App.Id;
       insert a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `insert App;` as the fifth line from the bottom. You never insert the `i360__Appointment__c` record.

Comment: Haha. Thank you so much, that took me a lot longer than I care to admit.

Comment: @NathanWhite If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.